# Detect who is logged on to remote Windows machines

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

How do you find out who is logged on to remote windows machines?

I'm using **psloggedon** at the moment, but it gives me only one computer at a time.

> **psloggeon \\172.21.0.5** 
>
>
>   [image: psloggedon]

Is there a better way how to scan a whole subnet ? Preferably some GUI application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [this script](http://www.ss64.com/nt/psloggedon_example.html). It scans a whole domain and gives you a nice output (computer name and user name).

**whoisloggedinwhere.bat > users.txt**

> ```
> @echo off
> setlocal
> for /f "Tokens=1" %%c in ('net view /domain:"%USERDOMAIN%"^|Findstr /L /C:"\\"') do (
>  for /f "Tokens=*" %%u in ('PsLoggedOn -L %%c^|find /i "%USERDOMAIN%\"') do (
>   call :report %%c "%%u"
>  )
> )
> endlocal
> goto :EOF
> :report
> set work=%1
> set comp=%work:~2%
> set user=%2
> set user=%user:"=%
> call set user=%%user:*%USERDOMAIN%\=%%
> @echo %comp% %user%
> ```

This script uses [PsLoggedOn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

not a GUI, but:

```
for /L %x in (2,1,254) do psloggedon \\172.21.0.%x
```

will do a scan from 172.21.0.2-254. You can also nest:

```
for /L %z in (16,1,31) do for /L %x in (1,1,254)  do psloggedon \\172.21.%y.%x
```

This will scan the 172.21.{16-31}.x subnets.

Comment: Good, but the problem is that it tries every IP address. If a host isn't active, it kinda hangs there for 30 seconds or so before it continues. The output is a bit messy as well.

Comment: you could do a ping against the machine(ping x.x.x.x -n 1) and check its output, that way your timeout against any machine is one second for the ping

Answer (score 2):

Try `nbtstat -a <computername>`

Comment: You asked 2 questions. This answers your first.

Answer (score 2):

I write the user name into the computer description property using a logon script, which lets me see everything in AD Users & Computers, do searches on it, and so on.  Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

If the servers are running Terminal Services, you can use Terminal Services Manager to view the servers in a domain and who is logged on to them.  It is GUI and can be found under

```
Start -> Administrative Tools -> Terminal Services Manager
```

Answer (score 1):

qwinsta is another dos command, but it'll still only give you one at a time...

```
C:\>qwinsta /server:test_srv
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 console           test_usr                  0  Active  wdcon
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen  rdpwd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect a user being *locally* logged on to a workstation by querying WMI through the following PowerShell script.  It returns the name of whoever is logged on locally or the empty string.

```
function logged_in($host_name) {
    (get-wmiobject -class Win32_ComputerSystem -computername $host_name `
        -namespace "root\CIMV2").UserName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where I got it but I have this code laying around that shows users on a machine.  You can wrap this in a for each loop to scan a bunch of machines.  I would say that if you want to know who's logged on to a system the simplest way is to turn on login auditing and look at (or query) the security log.  Here's the code to see who's on at any given moment:

```
' PARAMETERS
'
strComputer = "machineName"   ' use "." for local computer 
strUser = "domain\user" ' comment this line for current user
strPassword = "password" ' comment this line for current user

' CONSTANTS
'
wbemImpersonationLevelImpersonate = 3
wbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy = 6

'=======================================================================
' MAIN
'=======================================================================

' Connect to machine
'
If Not strUser = "" Then

    ' Connect using user and password
    '
    Set objLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set objWMI = objLocator.ConnectServer _
        (strComputer, "root\cimv2", strUser, strPassword)
    objWMI.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = wbemImpersonationLevelImpersonate
    objWMI.Security_.AuthenticationLevel = wbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy

Else

    ' Connect using current user
    '
    Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

End If

' Get OS name
'
Set colOS = objWMI.InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOS in colOS
    strName = objOS.Name
Next

If Instr(strName, "Windows 2000") > 0 Then

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Code for Windows 2000
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------

    ' Get user name
    '
    Set colComputer = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each objComputer in colComputer
        Wscript.Echo "User: " & objComputer.UserName
    Next

    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------

Else

    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Code for Windows XP or later
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------

    ' Get interactive session
    '
    Set colSessions = objWMI.ExecQuery _ 
          ("Select * from Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType = 2") 

    If colSessions.Count = 0 Then 
        ' No interactive session found
        '
        Wscript.Echo "No interactive user found" 
    Else 
        'Interactive session found
        '
        For Each objSession in colSessions 

            Set colList = objWMI.ExecQuery("Associators of " _ 
            & "{Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=" & objSession.LogonId & "} " _ 
            & "Where AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent" ) 

            ' Show user info
            '
            For Each objItem in colList 
                WScript.Echo "User: " & objItem.Name 
                WScript.Echo "FullName: " & objItem.FullName 
                WScript.Echo "Domain: " & objItem.Domain 
            Next 

            ' Show session start time
            '
            Wscript.Echo "Start Time: " & objSession.StartTime 
        Next 
    End If 

    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------

End If

'=======================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned loggedon2 yet, which I've been using for quite a few years. It's the GUI implementation you asked for and is available [here](http://assarbad.net/en/stuff).

Comment: When I run this on Windows 7, I receive the error:
Error - Quitting.
Could not find entry point for ServerBrowseDialogA0.

Perhaps it doesn't run on Win7?  Do you need admin rights to run it without an error?

Comment: @Steve, now I know why nobody else posted it. You're right, it doesn't work on Win 7, at least not the 64 bit version. I'm going to see if I can copy the required DLLs from an XP machine and get it working. I'll let you know if I have any success.