# Find Current user of a machine that is available in a LAN

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-command-prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error Opening HKEY_USERS for [COMPUTER NAME] PsLoggedon](https://serverfault.com/questions/408134/error-opening-hkey-users-for-computer-name-psloggedon)

We have a LAN that in which there is a `Windows Server 2003R2` with some clients. We have not set up an `Active Directory Server` so they are in a `Workgroup`. Is that possible to find the username of the logged on user on the client computers which are connected to the network, using just the IP addresses of the connected machines? (except administrator)

Also, is it possible to get a list of all the local user accounts on a `Workgroup` machine, with just the machine IP?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do? It is certainly not necessary to log in with the current logged in user...?

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. It is still not clear what you want to do. You can connect to those computers using "Administrator" and the administrator password. Is this what you want?

Comment: Sounds like someone did something bad, and now you're trying to find out who did it with only an IP address?

Comment: If my question is not clear, maybe I couldn't get my question across clearly. so it is better to just help solving the problem by asking for clarification rather than voting down.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh I completely agree.

Comment: Try to understand what this site is for, how it's used and who comes here before telling us how to run it - if you did you'd realise that downvoting (which I've not done, yet) is a by-product of people wanting your question closed - a perfectly valid one too given the VERY poor quality of it.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh, Well said. I don't understand why some people seem to get a sense of satisfaction by acting in such a condescending manner towards newcomers. We have to realise that not everybody has top notch writing skills and technical abilities, but that doesn't mean they should not be able to ask something in a public forum. I understand that some want to keep the quality of posts up here, but there is a way to do it properly.

Comment: @estranged - did you *see* the original question??

Comment: According to the site's stated guidelines, downvoting is a means of saying "your question is unclear." @Mehrdad, gravyface and estranged -- your understanding of the site is invalid.

Comment: OK OK Mates just calm down. I don't know how to ask this question. All I want is to remotely find the current User who is logged on a machine. imagine there is a computer A and a Computer B in a workgroup. I am working on Computer A. and computer B has different users. I know the IP of computer B. How can I find which user of computer B is currently working with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question...

No.  In order to get the information you want [remotely], you'd need to provide credentials to connect to the machine in the first place.  Since they're not domain joined, and you don't know the local administrator credentials (I think... do you?), you won't be able to use any tools to connect and see who's logged in locally.  This also applies to your question about local users.  To do it remotely, you require credentials to connect to the machine before you can even query that information.

If you did know the local credentials, you could use any number of tools, and/or the links MichelZ provided to connect to the machine and query it to find the the logged on users and/or the list of local accounts.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. and according to what you said, I can not find how many users are available in that machine as well (I mean retrieving a list of that machine's users)?  By the way you have completely understood my question. so will you please do me a favour and edit my question in a way it should be? I really don't know how to ask this question. thanks again.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, but same answer to that question.  To get user information, like the list of local users accounts that exist also requires credentials.

Comment: Thanks. But I asked you to edit my original question if it is convenient for you. Because I have gotten 4 vote down.

Comment: I did.  My change won't be visible until it's approved by a moderator, though.  I don't have enough rep to just edit anything without it being reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

Still guessing, but have a look at these questions:

[How to check who is currently logged on to windows workstation from command line?](https://serverfault.com/questions/32633/how-to-check-who-is-currently-logged-on-to-windows-workstation-from-command-line)

[Detect who is logged on to remote Windows machines](https://serverfault.com/questions/26264/detect-who-is-logged-on-to-remote-windows-machines)

[How to remotely see what users are logged into Windows 7 or Vista](https://serverfault.com/questions/229163/how-to-remotely-see-what-users-are-logged-into-windows-7-or-vista)

Comment: thanks for the links. the [first](http://serverfault.com/questions/32633/how-to-check-who-is-currently-logged-on-to-windows-workstation-from-command-line) one is similar to my question. but the answer doesn't work for me. it says: access is denied. I don't know what shall I do for that.